# Easy way to compute Queries Per Second value, based on log, with shell

Tags: logging, average, tail

We're able to tail the traffic on a server that we host :

```
...
+1287737841.266952 ...
+1287737841.267117 ...
+1287737841.267136 ...
+1287737841.278288 ...
+1287737841.278310 ...
+1287737841.278321 ...
+1287737841.278331 ...
+1287737841.278341 ...
...
```

As you can see they include timestamps, down to the micro-second!
I just want to be able to compute a floating QPS (Queries Per Second), and maybe per minute, and per hour from this. Any way of doing it with the shell?

Comment: what server platform is this?

Comment: Preet : custom server. Not OSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have bash available and that your log is on the file traffic.log, this would give you the number of queries per second:

cat traffic.log | colrm 1 1 | colrm 11 | uniq -c

This would give you the number of queries per minute:

for i in `cat traffic.log | colrm 1 1 | colrm 11`; do echo $(($i/60)); done | uniq -c

And this would give you the number of queries per hour:

for i in `cat traffic.log | colrm 1 1 | colrm 11`; do echo $(($i/3600)); done | uniq -c

I'm sure there must be a less CPU intensive way of doing it but this is the first thing that came to my mind.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Great! So, how many queries are you processing per second? ;)